# show popup in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I want to add popup when I click in link, this popup will contain the newsletter form in wordpress.

For that, I create in my html page this code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('OK!');
$(document).ready(function(e){
 
 $("#ouvrir_f").click(function(e){
  
  $(".arr_plan, .f_modale").css("display", "block");
  $(".arr_plan").animate({'opacity':'0.5'},350);
  $(".f_modale").animate({'opacity':'1'},350);
 });
 
 
 
});
</script>
```

```css
.arr_plan{background: grey;cursor: pointer;display: none;height: 100%;left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width:100%;  }
.f_modale{background: #ffffff; border: #000 solid 1px; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444; display: none; height: 220px; left: 30%; padding: 10px;position: absolute; top: 25px; width: 500px;}
.fermer{cursor: pointer; display: block; font-size; 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
.fermer:hover{text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="ouvrir_f" class="ouvrir_f">Ouvrir</a>
 <div class="arr_plan" ></div>
  <div class="f_modale">
   <span class="fermer">fermer</span>
   <h3>Titre fenetre modale</h3>
    <p>Bla bla bla bla .....</p>
  </div>
```

but when I click in the link, it doesn't show the popup.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - a working example specially for you:

http://codepen.io/Nikolaus91/pen/VaMOvJ

Didn't really check your solution, just know there is no chance it will work.
Attached modal is very simple. I would recommend using modals from Formstone.it or Foundation 6.

```
$(".show").on("click", function () {
    $(".mask").addClass("active");
});


function closeModal() {
    $(".mask").removeClass("active");
}

$(".close, .mask").on("click", function () {
    closeModal();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank s for your reply.

when I integrate this code to wordpress, it doesn't work.
When I click in the button, the pop up doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page?

Comment: I'd like but I installed wordpress in local

Comment: All that i want is to click in a link and to have a Pop Up with newslleter form in WordPress, is there any plugin or any other way to do it?

Comment: If so it's much easier then, for contact forms I always use Contact Form 7 because of it's simplicity and ease of use wherever I want it to implement.

I prefer to use my own modal windows, but few months ago I did use them as plugin called Easy Modal, they provide quite good docs and tutorials like this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9Us4ttVuZU

Provided link should solve all your troubles :)

Comment: and by easy modal I mean this plugin: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-modal/

Comment: thank you for your help.The solution is to add $ = jQuery; in the js file